# How do I adjust the period of my sine wave in my MATLAB code?

Tags: matlab

```
if(strcmpi(varargin(1),'sine'))%WIP. Sine SCORE 2/3 = 66%
array_t = sin(2*pi*Sig);
if nargin == 2
    s = array_t;
elseif nargin == 3 
    shift = cell2mat(varargin(3));
    array_t = sin(2*pi.*(Sig-shift));
    %plot(Sig,array_t)
    %grid on
    s = array_t;
elseif nargin == 4
    shift = cell2mat(varargin(3));
    Tau = cell2mat(varargin(4));
    array_t = (2*pi.*((Sig*Tau)+shift));
    %array_t = sin(Tau*x);

end
```

end

In this code I am passing through arguments which will affect how the waveform appears in the output. Note I am limited to the MATLAB, Image Processing, and Signal Processing toolboxes. **My question is simply how to affect the period of a sine wave in this code so it actually works**

Comment: What do you mean by "works". Please provide a clear example of input and desired output. Also, please include a minimal and **complete** function

Comment: You have to write questions so that people who have never seen your problem before can understand what is needed and what is wrong. This question falls far short. I can't even tell what variable is supposed to be time.